# Logic Apps XML Management

Tags: xml, azure, xsd, logic, azure-logic-apps

I have created Azure Logic Apps and Integration Account to manage our integrations.

We have an outbound API from our ERP system that pulls XML messages as per the below with Header information.

```
<TransmissionDetail>
    <Sender>XPILHRXPA</Sender>
    <Receiver>Isline</Receiver>
    <Subject>TRX_XDC_00000000000000097056_00000000000000144059</Subject>
    <CommCreated>2020-006-23 22:38:27</CommCreated>
</TransmissionDetail>
```

What we would like to achieve is that the Logic Apps to look at the "Receiver" tag. Depending of the value it would determine how logic apps manages this file with regards to transformation or transmission.

Can someone advise how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you requirement, you can refer to the steps below:

**1.** I initialize a variable named "**xmlString**" to simulate your xml message.
[image]

**2.** Initialize another variable named "jsonString" and use expression as below screenshot for its value.
[image]

**3.** Then we can use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the `jsonString` from the previous step.
[image]

You can click "**Use sample payload to generate schema**" and input the json data:

```
{
    "TransmissionDetail": {
        "Sender": "XPILHRXPA",
        "Receiver": "Isline",
        "Subject": "TRX_XDC_00000000000000097056_00000000000000144059",
        "CommCreated": "2020-006-23 22:38:27"
    }
}
```

to generate the schema automatically. Its schema should be:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "TransmissionDetail": {
            "properties": {
                "CommCreated": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Receiver": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Sender": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Subject": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

**4.** After that, we can get the value of `Receiver` tag. You can use a "**If**" condition in logic app to judge its value.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can just use the XPATH function in logic apps like this:

```
xpath(xml(body('My_XML_input')),'//*[local-name()="Receiver"]/text()')
```

This will give you the value of the "Receiver" XML tag.